# Using newline character to join multiple read_lines to a single string in r

Tags: r, string, newline

I'm trying to combine/join the lines read from a file into a single string. Please see code below.

My_object <- read_lines(file_name) %>% read_delim(comment = "?")

How do I convert all the lines read into a single string using newline character?
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to concatenate strings with `paste()` function? If you want the code, you will have to provide data. You can also use package `stringr` with function `My_object <- read_lines(file_name) %>% read_delim(comment = "?") %>% str_c(sep = "", collapse = NULL)`

Comment: Thanks. I used this 

My_object <- read_lines(file_name) %>% read_delim(comment = "?") %>% str_c(collapse = "\n")


Since I want to join them based on that character.

Comment: Does the code work?